# Suitable approach to test an API with 100 million records of multiple csvs having same column headers using Jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I am conducting rest API testing with JMeter using multiple CSV files having the same headers. The query parameters to request are 5 columns out of 30 columns of CSV file. Each CSV file has close to 1 million rows.

What would be the best approach to handle multiple CSV files with the same headers using CSV data set config and __CSVRead function to handle this scenario?

I am trying to come up an approach on below lines.

- Thread group = 1000(Concurrent, not simultaneous)
- Loop count = 10000
- For each file in a directory ( for loop iterating through directory)

  - CSV data set config as a child with below options:
          - Filename: ... (each file)
          - Variable Names: param1,param2,param3,param4,param5,
          - Delimiter: ,
          - Recycle on EOF = False
          - Stop Thread on EOF = True
          - Sharing Mode = All threads
- while loop controller condition (param1 ne EOF)

  - HTTP request

Questions are: 
How can I pass dynamically a CSV file to CSV data set config using BeanShell pre-processor scripting? 
Is there any plugin that can be used to handle multiple files as a JMeter variable and pass that variable to csv data set config during run time?

Comment: You might try https://sqa.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I have gone through sqa.exchange.com as well before I posed here.However I believe SO has more active users on Jmeter,so I took a chance.

Comment: There is a _really_ active Jmeter user on SQA, but he might be checking here as well... oohh... he already did ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass dynamic file names to the CSV Data Set Config, you should consider going for [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead.

Check out [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime/) article for more information on the implementation if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitri, I have gone through the __CSVRead() function and not sure if I understand it correctly, Is there any example that I can refer to to make it myself clear